# how can i calculate sum of PaidAmount that is made between two dates

Tags: t-sql

I have 3 tables which are Accounts, Payments, Statements. Table Accounts have all the accounts, table Payments have all the payments made to the account, and table Statements have all the statement data for the accounts.

Accounts

---

AccountID | DateOfDeath |

---

1001      | 2014-03-10  |

Payments

---

AccountID | PaidAmount | PaymentDate

---

1001      | 80.27      | 2014-07-09

---

1001      | 80.27      | 2014-06-10

---

1001      | 80.27      | 2014-05-12

---

1001      | 80.27      | 2014-04-13

---

1001      | 80.27      | 2014-03-15

---

1001      | 80.27      | 2014-02-14

---

Statements

---

AccountID | Balance | StatementDate

---

1001      | 0.00    | 2014-03-28

---

1001      | 1909.31 | 2014-02-25

I need to know the sum of PaidAmount (table Payments) in Payments table which is between the StatementDate (table Statements) of 2014-03-28 and 2014-02-25. The sum of the PaidAmount should have been 80.27 but I am getting 321.08. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or how can I write the query in a better way?

here is what I have so far

```
create table #temp1
(
    AccountID Numeric(9, 0)
    , DateOfDeath date
    , StatementDate date
    , Balance numeric(17,2)
)


insert into #temp1
(
    AccountID, DateOfDeath, StatementDate, Balance
)

select a.AccountID
  ,DateofDeath
  ,StatementDate
  ,Balance
from Accounts a 
inner join Statements b on a.accountID = b.accountID
where StatementDate in (select top 1 statementdate
                         from Statements
                    where AccountID = a.AccountID
                    and StatementDate >= DateOfDeath
                    order by StatementDate)
Order By a.AccountID, StatementDate

create table #temp2
(
    AccountId Numeric(9,0)
   , PaidAmount Numeric(10, 2)
   , PaymentDate date
)

select a.accountid, sum(a.Paidamount), max(a.PaymentDate)
from tblCreditDefenseInceptionToDateBenefit a
inner join #temp1 b on a.accountid = b.accountid
where a.paymentdate <= (select top 1 StatementDate from Statements
                        where AccountID = a.accountid
                   and statementdate >= b.dateofdeath
                   order by StatementDate desc)
and a.paymentdate > (select top 1 StatementDate from Statements 
                   where AccountID = a.accountid
                   and statementdate < b.dateofdeath
                   order by StatementDate desc)
group by a.accountid
order by a.accountid desc

select * from #temp2

drop table #temp1
drop table #temp2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can go about it a few ways

```
Create table #accounts
(AccountID int, Date_Death date)

insert into #accounts
(accountID, Date_death)
values 
('1001', '03/10/2014')

Create Table #payments
(AccountID int,  paidamt decimal(6,2), paymentdt date)
insert into #payments
(AccountID ,  paidamt, paymentdt)
values
('1001',    '80.27','07/09/2014'),
('1001',    '80.27','06/10/2014'),
('1001',    '80.27','05/12/2014'),
('1001',    '80.27','04/13/2014'),
('1001',    '80.27','03/15/2014'),
('1001',    '80.27','02/14/2014')
;


with cte as (
select 
Accountid,
case when paymentdt between '02/25/2014'and '03/28/2014' then (paidamt) else null  end as paidamt


from
#payments
)

Select
accountid,
SUM(paidamt)

from cte

group by
AccountID
```

or

put it in the where clause instead of doing a case statement, really depends onyour style

```
select
accountid,
sum(paidamt)paidamt

from 
#payments

where paymentdate >= '02/25/2014'
and paymentdate <= '03/282014'
```

or

if you want to use the statement table dates as parameters

```
with cte as
(
select 
a.AccountID, 
case when a.paymentdt between b.min_dt and b.max_dt then a.paidamt else null end as 'pdamt' 

from 
#payments as a
inner join 
        (select accountid, MIN(statementdt)min_dt, MAX(statementdt)max_dt from #statement group by accountid) as b on b.accountid = a.AccountID 
)

select 
AccountID, 
SUM(pdamt) as 'Paid Amount' 

from
cte

group by 
AccountID
```

again, could be added in where clase if you dontwant to do case staements